# How to replace consecutive non alphanumeric values with _

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string like

> aaa:::sss vvv ggg 4 SF 20 @text box2323

and i want to replace all non alphanumeric characters with single underscore.
Like this :

> aaa_sss_vvv_ggg_4_SF_20_text_box2323

What i tried so far is :

```
let nameRegex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]","g");
let originalName="aaa:::sss vvv ggg 4 SF 20 @text box2323";
let finalName= originalName.toLowerCase().replace(nameRegex, "_");
console.log(finalName);
```

but what i am getting is :

> aaa___sss_vvv_ggg_4_SF_20__text_box2323

As you can see i am getting 3 underscores at first replacement. I want single here.

Any help will be appricitated.

Comment: Remove `*` quantifier and use `+` instead.

Comment: Use `let nameRegex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g`, see https://regex101.com/r/jmsFwN/1

Comment: tried in regex101, replacing  `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+` (or simply `\W+`) with `_` should work.  (However, your original regex is going insert `_` between each alphabet, seems not aligned with what you observed)

Comment: @AdrianShum , on regexr its working fine but in code i am getting same as originalName with no changes

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, its working